# Google Sheet SUMIF not summing range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs, cumulative-sum

I am trying to SUM all rows based on the condition that a row's value is greater than 0. However, the formula is only calculating the first row and ignoring the rest of the range. I encountered this issue on a different spreadsheet but I isolated the issue on a new spreadsheet to show you and ask questions.

The answers should be B1 ($5), B2 ($15), B3 ($30). 
I followed the formula's usage as explained in the Google Docs https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en

The formula with respective row number `=SUMIF(A1, ">0", A$1:A1)`

[image]

---

Update - The below is my intended purpose. I have a spreadsheet that calculates money In and Out. For each of these transactions, I simply want the balance as a result of such transactions. This only works for the first row. (I hardcoded the values for the rest of the rows just to show my goal.)

[image]

Comment: If this works anything like Excel does, you should be able to move your cursor to B1 and drag that little square handle in the lower right hand corner of the cursor to B3 to get the result you want.

Comment: The same issue looks like is a bug in that **formula**

Comment: I've done that too including copy and paste, and I even typed the formulas on each B rows. The drag method correctly sets the row number. But the sum range is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A="",,SUMIF(ROW(A:A), "<="&ROW(A:A), A:A)))
```

[image: 0]

---

if you prefer dragging do:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()), ">0")
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D="",,
 SUMIF(ROW(D2:D), "<="&ROW(D2:D), D2:D)-
 SUMIF(ROW(E2:E), "<="&ROW(E2:E), E2:E)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I like your first solution. Please see my post update. How can I use your ARRAYFORMULA solution to make such calculations?

Comment: Elegant! Thanks.